# Каким образом клонировать слайды без библиотек на чистом js?

Tags: javascript, slider

Есть html:

```
<article class="bg-slider">
    <figure class="slides">
        <picture></picture>
        <picture></picture>
        <picture></picture>
    </figure>
</article>
```

Есть js:

```
slides = document.querySelector('.slides');
left = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        left = left - 100;
        slides.style.left = left + '%';
            if(left <= -200){
                left = 100;
            }               
    },5000)
```

Просто слайдер, который листает вбок содержимое `picture`. Что нужно дописать в `js` коде, чтобы после 3го слайда следом шел 1ый слайд? Или где глянуть инфу?(поисковик предлагает библеотеки)

Comment: вопрос как поменять местами элементы?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подумал подумал, и не очень понял. Хорошо, допустим поменял (на самом деле еще нет), а как отслеживать?

Comment: это я не понял что Вы хотите

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хороший ответ. Есть три слайда (3 картинки) в блоке с шириной равной 300%, по таймеру блок с картинками в родителе смещается на -100% (-100, -200). Я хочу чтобы после 3го слайда шел сразу же первый, потом второй, потом третий, потом снова первый и т.д. (зацикленность). Сейчас, когда достигается ширина -200% идет сбром на 0. Вот

Comment: Поноятно, если до того как доберусь до компа Вам еще не помогут, то и я попробую

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я буду очень благодарен

Comment: Первый дочерний элемент перемещается на место последнего очень просто `ElementSlides.appendChild( ElementSlides.firstElementChild )`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg я уже решил свою задачу сам. спасибо